# Bootbox Confirm on Form Submit

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, bootbox

I'm trying to get a form submission dialog (bootbox) to work in my ASP.NET Razor application. I have this JavaScript code:

```
   $(document).on("click", "#submit", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        bootbox.confirm("Are you sure for your choice: " + $this.val() + "?", function (result) {
            if (result) {
                $this.submit();
            } else {
                console.log("user declined");
            }
        });
    });
```

And my button is:

```
  <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <button type="submit" id ="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save"></span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However it doesn't work at all. I've imported the libraries and such and check if they're being loaded in Chrome and they are.

EDIT
Having updated the code (see above). The Bootbox dialog now appears but the form does not submit. If there are validation errors in the form when I click 'ok' it will notify the user. However once the errors are cleared and then they try to submit, it doesn't submit the form and nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try targeting the actual ID

```
$(document).on("click", "#submit", function (e) { ...
             //          ^^ the hash is important ...
```

Comment: Ok thats worked but the form doesn't submit when I press the Ok button

Comment: Ahh I see now forgot to actually tell it to submit the form. All sorted. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I don't know what element the form is, so I can't add that ?

Comment: Just had to put $this.submit(); in the if statement

Comment: Not fully working. If there are no validation errors in my form and I click the ok button on bootbox dialog, the form does not submit